# Using the tilde will select the adjacent div, but if I use a class name instead it won't.. Am I missing something?

Tags: css

Using the tilde will select the adjacent div, but if I use a class name instead it won't. Am I missing something?

```
checkbox:checked ~ div {
  visibility: visible;
}

checkbox:checked .menu {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: you are missing the `~`

Comment: Sorry put the question wrong. When I check the checkbox I want to select the .menu, but its in another container.. Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and then [edit] the question to add the clarification you left in that comment, and a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your selector to work the .menu class would have to be a child element of your checkbox.

If you want to select the .menu element and this element is a sibling/adjacent to the checkbox then you would need the tilde symbol still.

```
checkbox:checked ~ .menu {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanx!! that figures